# Is there a way to use TypeAdapter to be able to serialize both parent and child class instances

Tags: java, json, gson, jsonserializer

I am new to json and gson. I have a problem. I have a parent class and a child class which extends it. I have a list of parent class. Some of the entires are of child class. When I use gson api toJson(), I only get the fields that are defined in parent class. Can someone please give me an idea on how to implement TypeAdapter, to be able to get the fields of child class+parent class if it is an instance of child class and only fields of parent class otherwise

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java). That class isn't a part of core Gson (yet) but you can copy it into your project.